# Disable event bubbling on selectionchanged event- WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, routed-events, selectionchanged

I have a listbox inside a listview. on Both of them I have selectionchanged event. When I fire child control event parent control fires automatically. I need to stop this behaviour.
Any hints?
Thanks!

```
<ListView Name="listView1"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}" AlternationCount="2"
          SelectionChanged="listViewTask_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="150">
                <GridViewColumnHeader Name="gridViewColumnHeader1"
                                      Click="SortClick" Tag="Style"
                                      Content="Style"
                                      ToolTip="Click to Sort Style"/>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                             BorderBrush="White"
                             SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" 
                             Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Text}"
                             Style="{StaticResource Textblockstyle}"
                             ToolTipService.ShowDuration="360000000">
```

### --

Comment: I'm sorry my code got clipped.

Comment: <ListView Name="listView1" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RowStyle}" AlternationCount="2" SelectionChanged="listViewTask_SelectionChanged">
 <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" BorderBrush="White" SelectionChanged="listBox_SelectionChanged" 
Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding Text}" Style="{StaticResource Textblockstyle}" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="360000000">

Comment: Read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), code needs to be indented. Then edit your answer to account for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the OriginalSource property  in the selection changes event

```
if( ((ListView)e.OriginalSource).Name.Equals("name of the listview"))
  {
   // handle the event here...

  }
```

Answer (score 4):

In the inner handler set

```
e.Handled = true;
```